# Unknown Column in NEW

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `InitialCuring_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `specimen_register`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE DateOFJob1 Date;
    DECLARE SampleTime1 varchar(50);
    DECLARE Curing_LCDate1 varchar(50);
    DECLARE Curing_LCTime1 varchar(50);
    DECLARE DT1 DATETIME;
    DECLARE DT2 DATETIME;
    DECLARE ReportD Date;

    SELECT `DateOfJob`,`Sample_Time`,`Curing_LCDate`,`Curing_LCTime`,`ReportDue`

    INTO DateOFJob1,SampleTime1,Curing_LCDate1,Curing_LCTime1,ReportD

    FROM job_register j, test_register t
    WHERE j.JID = t.ParentID
    AND t.fts = NEW.FTS;

    SET DT1 = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DateOFJob1, ' ', SampleTime1), '%Y-%m-%d %H%i');
    SET DT2 = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Curing_LCDate1, ' ', Curing_LCTime1), '%Y-%m-%d %H%i');

    SET NEW.Initial_Cure = time_format(timediff(DT2,DT1),'%H');
    SET NEW.Due_Date = DATE_ADD(DateOFJob1,INTERVAL NEW.Age DAY);

    IF (NEW.Due_Date > ReportD) THEN
        SET NEW.ReportDue = NEW.Due_Date;
    END IF;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Returns Error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'ReportDue' in 'NEW'
```

ReportDue is in the job_register table, I've tried all manner of things and i cant seem to fix this.
I've tried using job_register.ReportDue and the alias j but it just dosen't work.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That syntax is product specific.)

Comment: thank's mate knew i forgot one